# moving objects withe key - diagonal

Tags: wpf, keyboard, wpf-controls, key, move

I need to move an object, I can move it up down and sideways, but fails in a diagonal, it is the way I made my move.

```
if (e.Key == Key.Up && Canvas.GetTop(Good) > 31)
            {
                double top = Canvas.GetTop(Good);
                Canvas.SetTop(Good, top - 7);
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Down && Canvas.GetTop(Good) < CanvasA.ActualHeight - 7 - Good.Height)
            {
                double down = Canvas.GetTop(Good);
                Canvas.SetTop(Good, down + 7);

            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Left && Canvas.GetLeft(Good) > -2)
            {
                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(Good);
                Canvas.SetLeft(Good, left - 7);

            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Right && Canvas.GetLeft(Good) < CanvasA.ActualWidth - Good.Width)
            {
                double right = Canvas.GetLeft(Good);
                Canvas.SetLeft(Good, right + 7);
            }
        }

    }
```

Everything works but can not click on the two buttons to move the character in a diagonal,
The reason that there is less than 31, it's because I did Menu in WPF.

Comment: you can move it diagonally by increasing left and top simultaneously

Comment: i am sorry its not working